# When I run flutter gallery loaclly, I faced with exception with Syntax Error when try to pub get

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Follow the document and switch my channel to master and upgraded.
2. git clone flutter/gallery project locally
3. follow the step run flutter pub get
4. pumped out:

> Generating synthetic localizations package failed with 1 error:

> Exception: Found syntax errors.

### Logs

```
       Exception: Found syntax errors.
       #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
       #1      generateLocalizationsSyntheticPackage (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/generate_synthetic_packages.dart:67:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #2      PackagesGetCommand._runPubGet (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:132:7)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #3      PackagesGetCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:175:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1275:27)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
       (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:290:9)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
       <asynchronous suspension>
```

### Flutter doctor shows

[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.7.0-13.0.pre.63, on Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.963], locale zh-CN)
• Flutter version 3.7.0-13.0.pre.63 on channel master at C:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository https://git.sjtu.edu.cn/sjtug/flutter-sdk.git
• FLUTTER_GIT_URL = https://git.sjtu.edu.cn/sjtug/flutter-sdk.git
• Framework revision 393e156c23 (5 hours ago), 2022-12-23 20:38:23 -0500
• Engine revision e3edfadbda
• Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-63.0.dev)
• DevTools version 2.20.0
• Pub download mirror https://mirror.sjtu.edu.cn/dart-pub
• Flutter download mirror https://mirror.sjtu.edu.cn

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from:
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
`flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✗] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at .
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
• Android Studio not found; download from for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.963]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.125
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 108.0.1462.54

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

I hope that someone would tell me how to solve with those Syntax Error problems and demonstrate how did it occurred.

Comment: You need Android SDK to build and run a flutter project. So the best option is to download Android Studio and try again

Comment: Thank u for ur advice, however, after I installed Android SDK, the problem still lies there...>: